# cts:value-match on xs:dateTime() type in Marklogic

Tags: regex, xml, datetime, xquery, marklogic

I have a variable `$yearMonth := "2015-02"`
I have to search this date on an element `Date as xs:dateTime`.
I want to use regex expression to find all files/documents having this date "2015-02-??"
I have `path-range-index` enabled on `ModifiedInfo/Date`
I am using following code but getting `Invalid cast` error

`let $result := cts:value-match(cts:path-reference("ModifiedInfo/Date"), xs:dateTime("2015-02-??T??:??:??.????"))`

I have also used following code and getting same error

`let $result := cts:value-match(cts:path-reference("ModifiedInfo/Date"), xs:dateTime(xs:date("2015-02-??"),xs:time("??:??:??.????")))`

Kindly help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are trying to use wild card search on Path Range index which has data type xs:dateTime().

But, currently MarkLogic don't support this functionality. There are multiple ways to handle this scenario:

1. You may create Field index.
2. You may change it to string index which supports wildcard search.
3. You may run this workaround to support your existing system:

   **for $x in cts:values(cts:path-reference("ModifiedInfo/Date"))
   return if(starts-with(xs:string($x), '2015-02')) then $x else ()**

This query will fetch out values from lexicon and then you may filter your desired date.

Comment: Hi Navin, I used above 3 ways and it helped. Thanks a lot once again

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by combining a couple cts:element-range-querys inside of an and-query:

```
let $target := "2015-02"
let $low := xs:date($target || "-01")
let $high := $low + xs:yearMonthDuration("P1M")
return
  cts:search(
    fn:doc(),
    cts:and-query((
        cts:element-range-query("country", ">=", $low),
        cts:element-range-query("country", "<",  $high)
      ))
  )
```

From the [cts:element-range-query documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-range-query):

> If you want to constrain on a range of values, you can combine multiple cts:element-range-query constructors together with cts:and-query or any of the other composable cts:query constructors, as in the last part of the example below.

Comment: the problem here is value "2015-02" is dynamic.  So i guess `starts-with` or replacing range index on Date from **dateTime** to string

Comment: I edited the code above to show a more dynamic approach

Comment: Heh. I realized I was answering for search, when you asked about values. You could use the $start parameter to cts:values() to jump to the right part of the lexicon, use "limit=31" to cap how many come back, then check what you get. Hmm, might be worth a separate answer.

Comment: I ran some tests and the string match approach looks like it's faster than what I had in mind.

Comment: Thanks, Dave. This is what i did initially, but then later I used `cts:values`

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider doing a cts:values with a cts:query param that searches for values between for instance 2015-02-01 and 2015-03-01. Mind though, if multiple dates occur within one document, you will need to post filter manually after all (like in option 3 of Navin), but it could potentially speed up post-filtering a lot..

HTH!